# Lists manipulation on tweeter

Tags: python, list, tweepy

I would like to see all lists of a twitter user, and see the members of each lists.

I've looked Tweepy doc, but i don't know how to use, and catch the Cursor..

Here's the function i will probably need to use :

```
API.lists([cursor])
API.lists_memberships([cursor])
API.get_list(owner, slug)
API.list_members(owner, slug, cursor)
```

I don't get how to stock the list, read all members then go to next list ..

It's obvious that we need to use some for to go from a list to a other.. but the Cursor ...

Thanks